# How can I know if my 98 Bmw 323i has the M pack?

Tags: bmw, 323i

A month ago I bought a **BMW E46 323i from 1998**, with 170 hp, the thing is that the former owner told me that it does have the M pack and it has many things with the M pack, such as stickers, carpets, a plate on the grill front, the sign as before it had an M3 sticker, and in the vehicle papers (I don't know if it was from Spain or Europe, it's called the same, but here is the Technical Sheet), among other things it says for example:

**Brand**:*BMW*

**Type**: *346L*

**Variant**:*AM31*

**Trade Name**: *Series 3 323i M*

Could someone tell me how I can know if it is an original M pack or a later one?

THX

Comment: Take your VIN to the dealer they can tell you what it come with.